# OnItemClick redirects to blank screen?

Tags: java, android, listview

listview.xml

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?-->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:id="@+id/lstText">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

ListView Code

```
package saint.animaltracking;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.List;

import saint.animaltracking.helper.AnimalAdapter;
import saint.animaltracking.helper.DatabaseHelper;

/**
 * Created by Kodie on 3/28/2016.
 */
public class selectAnimal extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private ListView lv;
    private List<animal> animal;
    private DatabaseHelper db;
    AnimalAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        db = new DatabaseHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        animal = db.getAllAnimal();
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstText);

        adapter = new AnimalAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, animal);

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                animal anim = (animal) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), specific.class);
                intent.putExtra("animal", anim);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

specific.class xml (Generic as I am trying to debug the issue)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnButton1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnButton3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnButton1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnButton3"
        android:layout_marginTop="94dp"
        android:text="User :"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnButton3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:text="Submit" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Specific.java code

```
package saint.animaltracking;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by Kodie on 5/2/2016.
 */
public class specific extends AppCompatActivity {
    String id;
    private SQLiteOpenHelper AT;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.specific);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
    }
}
```

The issue I am running into is that when I click the specific listview item to go to the specific animal, all it shows is a blank page. I'm not really sure why though, but I have a strong feeling it has something to do with the way I am writing the OnItemClickListener and OnItemClick or how it is passing the intent to the specific.java class? I've done just about everything I can think of (I've been working in android for about three weeks) to resolve this, outside of trying to rewrite the OnItemClickListener section. Any tips in the right direction are greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
I get the following messages repeatedly when clicking the listitem

> W/ViewRootImpl: Cancelling event due to no window focus: MotionEvent...
>
> E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb40d53a0

Comment: *I have a strong feeling it has something to do with the way I am writing the OnItemClickListener and OnItemClick or how it is passing the intent to the specific.java class?* ... rather because you never use an Intent  in `specific` class

Comment: @Selvin  I took that code out because I didn't know if it was the issue. I've tried passing it as an argument to onCreate as well as using getIntent().

Comment: Try to comment out intent.putextra line and run the app... i doubt you are passing object through intent

Comment: The issue remains without the putExtra.

Comment: I have updated the question with a log line that I am guessing could be relevant.

Comment: @Pramodmishra please respond

Comment: @Selvin please respond

Comment: try to debug your listview onitemClicklistener and check whats happening there.Or redirect to activity by setting up button click listener in adapter. if you tired then give me your source code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define some textview with random text in spesific class.. or something like Toast, to prove that spesific class is running or not.

Comment: I removed everything from the XML for specific and put a single large textview on it saying Toast. It does not show up.

Comment: please respond to my reply